# Default save extension in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I see Notepad adds .txt to the save name I choose. I can change this by changing file type when saving. But, next time I must change the file type again. How do I choose the default file type?

I see that my type is "Normal Text" in the Settings > Preferences. But, I see no "None" option there.

Comment: It bugs me too that a potentially powerful code editor makes the small things so annoying. Seriously: Who writes so many *.txt files?

Comment: I have Notepad++ v6.8.6 and I seem to have the opposite problem: it no longer saves to the default extension. If I save to filename "test" then Notepad++ no longer adds the ".txt" extension. This is very annoying as it requires me to constantly add the extension manually.

Comment: @Domi I write so many text files! :)  Several per day at least. I like using Notepad++ for writing meeting minutes

Comment: Ok, I just confirmed that my related problem in Notepad++ v6.8.6 (".txt" extension not being added by default) is a bug introduced in that version only. The bug gets fixed in v6.8.7 https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.8.7.html  "2. Restore file extension feature in save dialog."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a workaround [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/2577/).

You have to edit langs.xml.  On Windows, it is located in **%appdata%\notepad++**.  Change `< Language name="normal" ext="txt"/>` to `< Language name="normal" ext=""/>`.  Then set your default language to **Normal Text**.

Alternately, you could change a language you don't use if you wish to keep Normal Text for .txt files.  I chose makefile because I don't use it and there is only one setting for `#` comments.

Comment: FYI, the link in this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to save a file with a default extension of let's say, .c , everytime you use notepad++. You go into Settings -> Preferences -> File Association -> click C, C++,obj in Supported exts:     -> click .c -> press the (->) button o put it into Registered exts:    . You now will by default first choice, save as a .c file

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ 7.1 
From the menu, select:

Settings | Preferences | Default Directory.
Place a check-mark in the "Use new style save dialog.

When you save a file, manually add the file extension to control how the file is saved (file type).

Answer (score 0):

None of the options above worked for me, but this did:-

Settings -> Preferences -> MISC.  Then click **Set Save dialog file extension to .* instead of .txt for Normal Text**.

And then you add the extension you want.  I use a lot of .bib (BibTeX) files.

Answer (score 0):

This works on both 7.9.1 (32-bit) and 7.9.3 (64-bit) Windows 10 and Windows 7 respectively for me.

GOTO Settings -> Preferences -> New Document -> Default language: PHP (for instance)

Comment: Reread the question, they want `no extension`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.